# Solving $1+\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)=\cos(x)+\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following trigonometric equation

> $$1+\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)=\cos(x)+\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)$$

but I can't get any further than

$\iff 1 + 2\sin(2x)\cos(x) + \sin(2x) = 2\cos(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)$

$\iff 1 + \sin(2x)(2\cos(x) + 1) = \cos(2x)(2\cos(x) + 1)$

$\iff 1 + \sin(2x)(2\cos(x) + 1) = \cos(2x)(2\cos(x) + 1)$

$\iff 1 = (\cos(2x)-\sin(2x))(2\cos(x) + 1)$

Could someone point me out in the right direction?

Comment: You need to have an equation where one side is zero. Your last line does not achieve anything because $0.1 \times 10 = 0.01 \times 100 = 0.001 \times 1000 = 1$: the two brackets could be anything.

Comment: Where is this question from? I don't see any particular reason why one would expect this to have a "nice" solution, let alone solvable analytically

Comment: I can get [the roots on a period](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1%2Bsin%28x%29%2Bsin%282x%29%2Bsin%283x%29-cos%28x%29-cos%282x%29-cos%283x%29%3D0+on+%5B0%2C+2pi%5D) numerically, but division by $\pi$ doesn't give them obvious closed forms.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the Swiss army knife of trigonometry by setting $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$. One gets 
\begin{align}
\sin{x} &= \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \\
\sin{2x} &= 2\sin{x}\cos{x} = \frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}\\
\sin{3x} &= 3\sin{x}- 4\sin^3{x} =  \frac{6t}{1+t^2} - \frac{32t^3}{(1+t^2)^3} \\
\cos{x} &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
\cos{2x} &= \cos^2{x} - \sin^2{x} = \frac{t^4-6t^2 + 1}{(1+t^2)^2}\\
\cos{3x} &= 4\cos^3{x} - 3 \cos{x} = \frac{(1-t^2)^3}{(1+t^2)^3} - \frac{3(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
Substituting in your equation, and up to possible errors, one finally gets the equation
$$
t^6 + 2t^5 -3t^4 -8t^3 +11t^2 +6t -1 = 0
$$
which has two real roots and four complex roots. According to WolframAlpha, the real roots are
$0.136187$ and $- 0.548975$.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bsin%28x%29%2Bsin%282x%29%2Bsin%283x%29%3Dcos%28x%29%2Bcos%282x%29%2Bcos%283x%29

It looks like there are two real periodic solutions and 3 more complex ones.